# output tuple of numpy.histogram returs a tuple with two lists of different lengths

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

```
np.histogram([1,2,1,1,1,1,3,5], bins=[0,1,2,3,4,5])
```

returns me tuple with a list including the count how often a number occurs in my input list and the bin as a list.
The output looks like this:

```
(array([0, 5, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int32), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
```

if I want to print the data easy readable like:

```
0 occurs 0 times
1 occurs 5 times
....
```

How can I say that the four occurs 0 times?

Comment: If you want to count specific values rather than binning them, just use `Counter` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your particular case, you are looking for the left bin boundary (because it is included in the bin, while the right boundary is not - except for the last bin that includes its own right boundary, too). Function `zip` combines two lists/arrays. If one of the lists is longer, it is truncated, which is what you want:

```
hist = np.histogram([1,2,1,1,1,1,3,5], bins=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6])
for count, left_bin in zip(*hist):
    print(left_bin, count)
#0 0
#1 5
#2 1
#3 1
#4 0
#5 1
```